# Asp .Net Mvc трехуровневая архитектура

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, архитектура

Как правильно создать приложения на asp .net mvc 5 с трехуровневой архитектурой используя identy 2.0?

У меня есть приложение на ASP.NET MVC5, состоящее из трех слоев: PLL, BLL, DAL. В DAL расположены репозитории для работы с БД, в BLL лежат хелперы, к каждой сущности. В PLL непосредственно расположены модели, вьюхи и контроллеры, в контроллерах естественно используются методы из BLL.

Кроме того в PLL находятся классы Identy 2.0. То есть в моем приложении имеются два Db контекста, что несомненно приведет к коллизиям.

Я хочу узнать как распределить классы Identity 2.0 в моем приложении так, что бы они использовали единственный DB контекст расположенный в DAL. То есть имеется цель переделать ПОЛНОСТЬЮ мое приложение под трехслойную архитектуру.

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под "правильно"? MVC - это просто паттерн организации Presentation, одного из трех уровней. Придерживайтесь паттерна, не пишите код бизнес-логики в контроллерах, и все будет более-менее правильно.

Comment: Наверное имеется ввиду то что идентити пуляет в базу, которая при 3-х звенке прямо не доступна из сайта.

Comment: Возможно поможет: 
http://habrahabr.ru/post/227351/, 
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-recommended-resources

Comment: @cpp_user возможно. но но не хотелось бы гадать :)

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос слишком общий и может иметь конкретного решения.

Comment: Да что там общего то? Нужно реализовывать своего custom user provider-а для идентити чтобы перебросить данные по трехзвенке в свое хранилище.

Comment: Создайте пустое MVC5 приложение и воспользуйтесь этим наггетом: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.1.0-alpha1 Потом настройте подключение к бд и все.

Comment: @Bezarius Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: @Nicolas Chabanovsky это комментарий, а не ответ.

Comment: @Bezarius Николас намекает, что отвечать надо в формате ответов, а не в комментариях. Ответы в комментариях - зло.

Comment: @PashaPash если бы вопрос не залочили, ответил бы в ответах, а не в комментах :)

Comment: @Bezarius ну так перенесите сейчас - всего делов-то. я свой ответ написал только потому, что было накидано ссылок в комментах :)

Comment: @PashaPash нуу, вечером сделаю в виде ответа :)

Comment: Вы просто список своих `DbSet` вынесите в контекст Identity. Вам ничего не мешает это сделать и Ваша проблема с двумя контекстами будет решена.

Answer (score 2):

Если вас не устраивют стандартные методы, которыми Identity 2.0 работает с базой, вы можете полностью заменить из на свои:

Объявить свой тип для пользователя:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IUser
{ ... }
```

Объявить свой тип хранилища пользователей и реализовать его с использованием уже существующего BLL/DAL:

```
public class CustomUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>
{ ... }
```

Объявить наследника от UserManager:

```
public class CustomUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public CustomUserManager(CustomUserStore store)
         : base(store)
    {
        this.PasswordHasher = new CustomPasswordHasher();
    }

    public static CustomUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<CustomUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        var manager = new CustomUserManager(new CustomUserStore<ApplicationUser>());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

и зарегистрировать `CustomUserManager` в App_Start:

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomUserManager>(CustomUserManager.Create);
```

`CustomUserStore` и `CustomUserManager` переностите или в BLL, или частично оставляете в PLL (зависит от того, как вы их реализуете). Я бы оставил их в PLL, вписав в их методах вызовы BLL.

---

Или, возможно, вам будет достаточно стандартной реализации `UserStore`, тогда достаточно будет создать пустой класс-наследник `CustomUserManager` и зарегистрировать и его, и фабрику для контектов:

```
public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
{
    return new ApplicationDbContext();
} 

public static CustomUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<CustomUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var manager = new CustomUserManager((new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>())););
    return manager;
}


public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationDbContext>(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomUserManager>(CustomUserManager.Create);
}
```

<sub>Код вживую не проверял, но должно работать</sub>

Answer (score 0):

[Вот здесь](http://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/23.10.php) неплохо описан процесс внедрения Identity в трехуровневую архитектуру