# ASP.NET MVC 5. Аутентификация и авторизация из пользовательской базы

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Есть готовая база данных, в которой прописаны данные по пользователям, и их ролям. База использовалась в настольной программе, теперь встала задача перевести работу в WEB. К сожалению, пока сам не очень силен в ASP.NET. 
Нужно, используя, данные из базы сделать аутентификацию и авторизацию пользователя. Почитал на эту тему статьи и документацию, как понимаю все сводится к ASP.NET Identity. Но во всех рассмотренных примерах используется создание новых таблиц, что в моем случае неприемлемо. Нужно, чтобы пользователь авторизовался, а я зная его Роль мог разрешать или не разрешать те или иные действия. 
Нужен ваш совет, как лучше решить задачу, что использовать.

Comment: в Identity можно использовать свои store для пользователей, ролей и прочего - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/454424/177221

Comment: Перенести данные из старых таблиц в новые?

Comment: Ещё вариант - переопределить стандартные провайдеры `MembershipProvider` и `RoleProvider`

Comment: @cpp_user Перенести нельзя, т.к. с базой еще работать будут и в настольной версии программы

Comment: @qzavyer а разве `MembershipProvider` не старая технология для MVC 5, ее вроде уже не рекомендуют?

Comment: @PashaPash если правильно понимаю, то необходимо создать в ручную `ApplicationUser : IUser`, `CustomUserStore : IUserStore<ApplicationUser>` и `CustomUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>` и `Роль` и при аутентификации пользователя создать и заполнить данными по текущему пользователю. А затем во всех контроллерах мне будет доступна возможность атрибутом н-р `[Authorize (Roles="admin")]` фильтровать доступность тех или иных `View`. Правильно?

Comment: @FMA да. MembershipProvider, кстати, тоже вполне рабочий вариант - но его сложнее аккуратно переопределить - он слишком монстро.

Comment: @PashaPash Спасибо большое, буду пробовать предложенный вариант.